# Meaning of natural homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, group-homomorphism

When I reached the homomorphism concept in group theory, I thought that "natural" is only an ordinary literal word without mathematical meaning. But I read somewhere that this word has a precise mathematical meaning in the theory of categories.

I am not familiar with category theory; only I know it deals with morphisms.

Could you explain me the meaning of "natural" in the category theory?

Comment: The word canonical is used as well.

Comment: A natural or canonical morphism is a simple and obvious morphism. I don't know a general definition, but there should be one, because I'd never noticed that a canonical morphism isn't unique.

Comment: This wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup mentions natural as in "the homomorphism generated by a given normal subgroup", see also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776039/intuition-behind-normal-subgroups/3732426#3732426

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Natural" can be given a precise meaning using the concept of [natural transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation). For example, loosely speaking, for any group $G$ there is a "natural" homomorphism $[G, G] \to G$, where $[G, G]$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$, and similarly there is a "natural" homomorphism $G \to G/[G, G]$. In fact there is a "natural" short exact sequence

$$1 \to [G, G] \to G \to G/[G, G] \to 1.$$

Natural transformations allow you to remove the quote marks in everything I said above. The three constructions $[G, G], G, G/[G, G]$ above can be upgraded to three [functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) $\text{Grp} \to \text{Grp}$ from the category of groups to itself, and the morphisms above are the components of natural transformations between these functors. Explicitly, this means that if $f : G \to H$ is a group homomorphism, then there are two induced homomorphisms $[G, G] \to [H, H]$ and $G/[G, G] \to H/[H, H]$ such that a certain [diagram commutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as I said in my question, I am not familiar with category theory. Is there any easy explanation ?