# A problem related to the definition of group extension

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a group extension, wikipedia said that the group $N$ is isomorphic to a **normal** subgroup in $G$. However, how can I deduce it? Can't see the reason directly. Or am I misunderstand it?

[image]

Comment: It's the definition of a short exact sequence for groups. You need that condition so that the quotient makes sense as well.

Comment: $N$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $G\to Q$.

Comment: I see! The kernel of a homomorphism must be normal.

Comment: @lulu Wait... Why $N$ is the kernel of $G\to Q$? Is it part of the definition of group extension?

Comment: That's part of the definition of an [exact sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ShortExactSequence.html).

Comment: This may also help with some intuition about it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776039/intuition-behind-normal-subgroups/3732426#3732426